# IntelliJ personal developer license. Can I use for developing for another company? (complicated)

Tags: software-industry

my case is following: I am a developer (D), I bought IntelliJ Personal license.
I am also self employed (SE), but I bought license for me, personal. Is it legal to use this license when I am writing code for other company (OC) as a subcontractor? 
What if OC is also a subcontractor of another company (AC)? May I use a license even then?

So the chain is following:

1. OC is working for AC as a subcontractor.
2. SE is working for OC as a subcontractor.
3. OC gives SE "resource" to a project for AC.
4. SE is one person company: D.
5. D has a private license of IntelliJ.
6. Can D use this license for working actually for AC?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software licenses, not navigating the workplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be absolutely sure, contact IntelliJ, but from what I gather from their website on (https://sales.jetbrains.com/hc/en-gb):

> - Commercial licenses are the standard licensing option for companies. They can be used by anyone working for the company that owns the licenses.
> - A personal license is the discounted licensing option for a private individual purchasing a license by and for himself (herself).

They even state (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/buy/license-matrix.jsp):

> Personal License available to:
>
> Private individuals purchasing with their own funds. Cannot be purchased or reimbursed by companies. Can be used on company hardware if purchased privately

So you should be able to use the license like you say, without any repercussions. It doesn't matter if you write code for your hobby, a freelance project or even a company you currently work for! The commercial license is only there so companies can get a tax refund or discount, and so it can be used by *any* employee in the company.